# Allow Users to Perform mySQL Select Statements While Preventing SQL Injections

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I was planning on making an HTML form. The form will display the current table in the database as shown below

```
Toy  | Color
Ball |  Red
Bat  |  Yellow
Glove|  Brown
```

At the end of the form, it should say "Make a query that gets all the toys and its respective color". So then users would be allowed to type in the select query. Please note the questions could vary so there isn't a consistent query that the user will always have to use. In essence, they have to write the ENTIRE query. I was wondering how should I go about this to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: Uh, if you're forcing the user to write an entire sql statement, then by definition you're FORCING them to do sql injection on your system.

Comment: Allowing users to post a full query to your database IS a database injection. You're basically allowing people to freely post queries to your database. A simple DROP * FROM * will wipe your database.

Comment: If `SELECT` is the ONLY thing you want them doing then I would create a MySQL user with nothing but select permissions for that table and log in as that user for the DB interaction.

Comment: So no combination of blacklisted post words, my_sqli, pdo, and creating on the fly temporary table would help?

Comment: it is always a good idea to explain, *why* do you need that

Comment: The form represents a test to student, other than having the teacher manually looking at the query, it seemed easier to automate it in a way

Comment: @user1709294 For this particular use case, I'd suggest parsing the query yourself and tell them what went wrong if it isn't what you were expecting. Oh, and don't run it against a live database.

Comment: I am tempted to write a comment regarding such a teacher, but unfortunately, it would be offtopic.

Comment: Perhaps you could make use of [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) somehow. But I guess it would be hard for you to verify the query then...

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in the comment, you can not safely do this on a live environment.

However...

If this is for educational purposes I would suggest you create a local environment on your students systems (XAMPP or the likes) and let them tinker in scripts you have premade for them.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the permissions on your MySQL user to ensure they are permitted to run `SELECT` statements only, and only against a single database. This will allow students to experiment with maximum flexibility, and not be hindered by an overly restrictive filtering strategy.

If you run this using PDO in an exception handler, you should be able to catch any malformed queries, whether deliberate or not. If the user attempts to run a statement that is not a `SELECT`, that will result in a PDO Exception which can also be caught and handled gracefully.

A commenter raises a good point about users running demanding queries that will swamp the host machine. To mitigate against this, you could try to find a MySQL configuration setting that sets a maximum query time. I couldn't myself find a MySQL setting that would do this, but PostgreSQL offers `statement_timeout`.

If that is not possible, consider running the query in an AJAX operation in which PHP's maximum execution time is limited to a few seconds. You could consider doing this in SQLite, in order to avoid using a shared database server resource - since in the case of SQLite there *is* no database server.

Another idea: I believe the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) tool uses a strategy of wrapping potentially risky queries in a transaction, fetching the results and then rolling back at the end. That might be worth considering too, though setting the permissions should be sufficient on its own.

Comment: as though limiting permissions to SELECT has anything to do with injections

Comment: @YourCommonSense, aw cheer up! Life is not as bad as you think `:)`.

Comment: @halfer It is when they run a ridiculous join and slow down your database so much that it isn't usable. And that's just thinking of what could happen on *accident*.

Comment: @bfrohs: ...for instance, if they actually wanted to hurt things, they could use something like the MySQL `BENCHMARK()` function.

Comment: @bfrohs, that's a fair point. Does MySQL have a configurable maximum statement execution time to deal with that problem? Limiting statements to a second or two should be okay, if the database will be small and suitable for educational purposes.

Comment: Based on everyone's comment, I'm going to compare the correct SQL statement and the student's statement by comparing two tree structures. This seems to be the safest way

Comment: @user1709294: that would certainly work - I believe that there are PHP libraries that can do SQL parsing. But, if SQLFiddle can allow _write_ operations from anonymous users, what you want appears to be possible to do safely. If I were handed this project, I'd try using a database.